# How much did Buddha walk in his lifetime?

Tags: history

How many miles(kilometers) did Buddha walk during his life? According to one [source](https://www.lionsroar.com/walking-in-the-footsteps-of-the-buddha/), "*The entire pilgrimage route is within the span of about 350 miles east to west and 250 miles north to south, and the Buddha is known to have walked across it many times.*"

Answer (score 1):

He travelled hundreds of kilometres. From Lumbini to Sarnath to kapilvastu to Pataliputra to bodh gaya to khushinagar. You can not calculate exact number of kilometers because it is not known which path he took. He had the ability to vanish from some point and spontaneously reappear at other.

The suttacentral.net is not working for mobile browsers therefore I am unable to give links. But in DN 16 sutta it is said that “the Buddha with the mendicant Sangha , vanished from near shore and landed on the far shore”.